# Parsing error in jsonlite reading multiple validated json files in R

Tags: r, json, jsonlite, rjson

I'm new to json files in R. I got some json files for STONKS are you can see scraped online. The werid thing is each individual json file can be read perfectly using fromJSON from the jsonlite library. I have taken individual files to check on jsonlint.com to validate, and the web confirmed they are valid json files.

I have tried to use the validate () from jsonlite on single files, but there the file failed to pass the validation.

However, when I want to use lapply to read all the files R gave me error on

```
Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                   No data available for the given
```

Here are my simple codes:

```
library(tidyr)
library(jsonlite)

ls <- list.files(pattern = "*.json")

Data.fromJson <- lapply(ls, fromJSON)
```

Sorry but I think the problem might be with the data so I dont want to just trim it and make dummy as it might mess things up. Instead I have uploaded a few json files to my google drive and here is the link:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zM4vj1TIseFKBSiNWe5yMY9BJPg-CIsv?usp=sharing

Comment: I cannot replicate that error with your example files. What does seem odd is your `ls <- list.files(pattern = "*.json")` line. Does that return the files you expect? The `pattern=` arguemtn expects a regular expression, not a grob. I would have expected something like `ls <- list.files(pattern = "\\.json$")`

Comment: @MrFlick hmmm strange. The ls<- list.files() seemed to work fine though, it returned the character vector containing all the file names, displaying correctly , eg "ADBE-10-Day.json".....   Do my code worked fine in your hand?

Comment: I got no errors reading on the data you provided. Everything was imported as a list. Do you get this error when you try to import these three files alone? It will be very hard to help without a proper reproducible example.

Comment: @MrFlick I knew what went wrong and you are right my friend. Indeed I also got the parsing error using the 3 files but then I noticed one odd thing, the char vector is 4 instead of 3. Then with what you commented on "\\.json$". What happened is I named my R code as Read json xxxx, and my fromJSON is trying to read my R code file..... classic screw up

Comment: @MrFlick Strange things happened. If i change the name of the code, the 3 fiels run just fine. but when I deploy to all the files, problem remains the same error. I used the validate() on single file, the error says "lexical error: invalid char in json text.\n                                       YUM-30-Day.json\n                     (right here) ------^\n"

Comment: Are you sure you have the working directory set properly? The file paths you pass should be relative to the current working directory. If `fromJSON` cannot file a file with the name passed, it will try to interpret the filename itself as a JSON string which sounds like what is causing this particular error message.

Comment: @MrFlick thank you for the patience for a noob. If I read just a single file, fromJSON is fine. If I try to use validate() on the single file, R tells me False and gave me the above error. I did set the working directory to the folder. Now If I ran the apply() of the fromJSON, I get "Error in parse_con(txt, bigint_as_char) : 
  lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       No data available for the given
                     (right here) ------^"

Comment: Without a proper reproducible example there's nothing more I can really say. It's probably still a file path problem of some sort. Sorry I can't help further.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes I know this is frustrating. And I appreciate your help. I have updated the link to include all the data to the folder. Maybe this time it could give you the error.

Comment: Look at the files by size. Some are very small for example "GII-20-Day.json" That file doesn't contain valid JSON data. It's unclear what you want to do with that file.

Comment: @MrFlick these data are given to me. Perhaps I should work on the ones with decent size and test if that works

Comment: @MrFlick again, I have to thank you. that 3 files with the same ticker is a literal string with no ''". that's why jsonlite complains

Comment: ML33M, two ideas. I get ofthen these kinds of problems when I load in Windows(i.e. Windows 1252 encoding) jsons encoded and captured in UTF-8.
The way I handle this is to create a function with an if {} else {} so that if fromJSON() can not read the json, it saves the input path in a seaprate txt. When the process is over I jsut manually check the files logged in said txt.